# Number of Performance Monitoring Units in ARM Cortex-A53

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi3

How many performance monitoring units (PMU) are in ARM Cortex-A53? Is there one PMU for each core or one PMU for the whole processor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one per core. You can kind of infer this from seeing one entry for each in the ROM table.

In the [Cortex-A53 TRM](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0500d/DDI0500D_cortex_a53_r0p2_trm.pdf), Fig 2-1 alludes to debug being located per core, and 2.1.9

> • ARM v8 debug features in each core.

I don't see anything explicit that there is one PMU instance per core (architectural or not), but it's possible that I missed this since there are a few places where it might be specified.

Section 11.10.1 describes the debug memory map, consisting of a ROM table (index of other components in this group), then CPU debug, CTI, PMU and Trace *for each core*. To check what is present, you need to read DBGDRAR to find the base of the ROM table, and check bit[0] of the entries listed in Table 11-28. In a 4-core A53, you should find that all 16 devices are present.

One further point, although the PMU is per core and generally counts the events for the core, there *can* be some processor level events which are visible equally to all PMUs.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. Would you mind sharing resources which support your answer? Also, would you explain how can I infer number of PMUs from ROM table?

Comment: I've seen the source code - but yes, I can try and find a public reference. Not sure there is much that is explicit. Some ROM table info is here http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.epm039795/coresight_technical_introduction_EPM_039795.pdf but I'm not sure if it has the right detail to answer this.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information. Also, Table 11-26 from Cortex-A53 TRM shows the address offset of each PMU.